# AND / OR Conditional Formatting for Google Sheets with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to write a custom formula to conditional format column E by referring to the different tenure level targets in column D to indicate if they are hitting their targets base off of their tenure level. I wrote the formula below and it didn't come out right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Trying to say: `If D3 = "new" or "beginner" or "intermediate" or "veteran",
Then F3 >= D24 or F3 >= D25 or F3 >= D26 or F3 >= D26`.

`=if(or($D4="new",$D4="beginner",$D4="intermediate",$D4="veteran"),OR($E4>=$D24,$E4>=$D25,$E4>=$D26,$E4>=$D27))`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
=((E4>=D$24)*(D4=C$24))+((E4>=D$25)*(D4=C$25))+((E4>=D$26)*(D4=C$26))+((E4>=D$27)*(D4=C$27))
```

[image: 0]